# The application of dipole antenna - Dipole Antenna

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Why are dipole antenna used to feed more elaborate directional antennas such as horn antenna, parabolic reflector?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an input signal for a more elaborate/complicated antenna (system). So a dipole can be part of a Yagi array acting as the driven element with the other elements and the reflector proving a directional signal as is also the case with a dipole at the focal point of a parabolic reflector.

A dipole is simple to design and is comparatively easy to make.
It can be folded to change its impedance to get a better match when used as part of, say, a Yagi antenna.

Comment: Can you please explain how can the dipole antennas provide an input signal fro complicated antenna (systems)?

Comment: @ThaoNguyen From the transmitter/receiver a cable sends the signal to/from a dipole which is part of the antenna system.